# how to use jquery get the event?

Tags: jquery, events

the code is like this:

```
<a onclick="ajaxClick()">aaa</a>
```

now i want to get the event in function ajaxClick(){ //? }
since the code is loaded from ajax request, so there is noway to use bind(). 
is there any jquery API could do this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind to existing and future elements:

```
var ajaxClick = function() {
  //your handler
};

jQuery("a").live("click", ajaxClick);
```

Remove the `onClick="ajaxClick()"` and use the above code instead. If you're using jQuery it's better to use it to bind to events instead of mixing up techniques. jQuery also normalizes event-handling across browsers, so it's easier to deal with events.